# Soapui screen crashes.

Tags: soapui

SoapUI does not seems to work properly.. when i am moving my mouse, the screen duplicates itself.. when i am moving the application to my other screen.. its over. until i move my mouse again..

[image: Screenshot of my soapui]

Version: SoapUI 5.3.0
OS: Windows 10

I have tried:

- Updated videodrivers.
- Updated Java
- Previous versions of SoapUI.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Do you got big or 4k screen or something like that?

Comment: I've got a 1600 x 1200 screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off Direct3D for Java may help. Set the environment variable 'J2D_D3D' to false.